# Force image to overflow padding of parent div and be 100% wide

Tags: html, css

I want images with class `wide` to go over the parent div's padding. When I give them negative margin to do it, they don't stretch to full width (`max-width:100%` keeps them the same size).

```css
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* regular images */

#content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* full width images, videos etc */

#content .wide {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet non libero eget ornare. Proin commodo tortor risus, vitae malesuada lectus pharetra quis. Aliquam quis elit in erat facilisis pellentesque. Donec ornare ligula eu massa dignissim posuere
    sed eu sapien.</p>

  <!-- this should stretch -->
  <img class="wide" src="http://pic.templetons.com/brad/pano/europe/epidaurus-wide.jpg">

  <p>orci. Proin nec nunc pulvinar, feugiat lorem in, imperdiet ante. Proin interdum quam id congue tincidunt. Praesent pellentesque facilisis dictum. Nulla vel nulla turpis. Fusce mauris elit</p>

  <!-- this one should NOT -->
  <img src="http://pic.templetons.com/brad/pano/europe/epidaurus-wide.jpg">

  <p>orci. Proin nec nunc pulvinar, feugiat lorem in, imperdiet ante. Proin interdum quam id congue tincidunt. Praesent pellentesque facilisis dictum. Nulla vel nulla turpis. Fusce mauris elit, s</p>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it? I want the image to be left to right without no spaces on sides.

Images without the class `wide` should be contained inside the paddings as normal.

(ps. giving margin to everything but the images *will* work, but it's a lot of work and not very elegant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest adding markup as [isherwoord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862155/1150683) suggested, which would allow for better browser support than my answer. If that is not possible, you can use the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to add the negative margins to the 100% width. Browser support isn't even [*that* bad](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)!

```css
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* regular images */

#content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* full width images, videos etc */

#content .wide {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  max-width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet non libero eget ornare. Proin commodo tortor risus, vitae malesuada lectus pharetra quis. Aliquam quis elit in erat facilisis pellentesque. Donec ornare ligula eu massa dignissim posuere
    sed eu sapien.</p>

  <!-- this should stretch -->
  <img class="wide" src="http://pic.templetons.com/brad/pano/europe/epidaurus-wide.jpg">

  <p>orci. Proin nec nunc pulvinar, feugiat lorem in, imperdiet ante. Proin interdum quam id congue tincidunt. Praesent pellentesque facilisis dictum. Nulla vel nulla turpis. Fusce mauris elit</p>

  <!-- this one should NOT -->
  <img src="http://pic.templetons.com/brad/pano/europe/epidaurus-wide.jpg">

  <p>orci. Proin nec nunc pulvinar, feugiat lorem in, imperdiet ante. Proin interdum quam id congue tincidunt. Praesent pellentesque facilisis dictum. Nulla vel nulla turpis. Fusce mauris elit, s</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, I thought `calc()` is still in distant future! I'll use this instead of the extra markup, as it's used in Markdown articles and adding wrappers would be problematic

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stretching the image with negative margins, add a container element:

```css
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* regular images */

#content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* full width images, videos etc */

#content .wide {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet non libero eget ornare. Proin commodo tortor risus, vitae malesuada lectus pharetra quis. Aliquam quis elit in erat facilisis pellentesque. Donec ornare ligula eu massa dignissim posuere
    sed eu sapien.</p>

  <!-- this should stretch -->
  <div class="wide">
    <img src="http://pic.templetons.com/brad/pano/europe/epidaurus-wide.jpg">
  </div>

  <p>orci. Proin nec nunc pulvinar, feugiat lorem in, imperdiet ante. Proin interdum quam id congue tincidunt. Praesent pellentesque facilisis dictum. Nulla vel nulla turpis. Fusce mauris elit</p>
</div>
```